# where does the BroadcastReceiver intent come from? and how can I change it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

in the app I'm working on, whenever the user receives a message, the message contents get delivered to the app using a `BroadcastReceiver`. I want to add a field to this intent and get some extra information, just don't know where does the intent come from.

Here is the broadcast and its `onReceive()` method:

```
br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            int task = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_TASK, 0);
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(PARAM_STATUS, 0);

            int msgId = intent.getIntExtra("msgId", 0);
            long msgFromUserId = intent.getLongExtra("msgFromUserId", 0);
            int msgFromUserState = intent.getIntExtra("msgFromUserState", 0);
            int msgFromUserVerify = intent.getIntExtra("msgFromUserVerify", 0);
            String msgFromUserUsername = intent.getStringExtra("msgFromUserUsername");
            String msgFromUserFullname = intent.getStringExtra("msgFromUserFullname");
            String msgFromUserPhotoUrl = intent.getStringExtra("msgFromUserPhotoUrl");
            String msgMessage = intent.getStringExtra("msgMessage");
            String msgImgUrl = intent.getStringExtra("msgImgUrl");
            int msgCreateAt = intent.getIntExtra("msgCreateAt", 0);
            String msgDate = intent.getStringExtra("msgDate");
            String msgTimeAgo = intent.getStringExtra("msgTimeAgo");
            int msgTransactionValue = intent.getIntExtra("transValue",0);

            Chat1Item c = new Chat1Item();
            c.setId(msgId);
            c.setFromUserId(msgFromUserId);
            c.setFromUserState(msgFromUserState);
            c.setFromUserVerify(msgFromUserVerify);
            c.setFromUserUsername(msgFromUserUsername);
            c.setFromUserFullname(msgFromUserFullname);
            c.setFromUserPhotoUrl(msgFromUserPhotoUrl);
            c.setMessage(msgMessage);
            c.setImgUrl(msgImgUrl);
            c.setCreateAt(msgCreateAt);
            c.setDate(msgDate);
            c.setTimeAgo(msgTimeAgo);
            c.setTransactionValue(msgTransactionValue);

Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onReceive: task = " + task + ", status = " + status + " " + c.getMessage() + " " + Integer.toString(c.getId()));



            final Chat1Item lastItem = (Chat1Item) 
listView.getAdapter().getItem(listView.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);

            messagesCount = messagesCount + 1;

            chat1List.add(c);

            if (!visible) {

                try {

                    Uri notification = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), notification);
                    r.play();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            scrollListViewToBottom();



            getNextMessages();
        }
```

it also uses an IntentFilter to register the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
    IntentFilter intFilt = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(br, intFilt);
```

also these are the intent-filters that are in my manifest file:

```
       <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        <service
            android:name="com.thetasocial.app.service.MyFcmListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.thetasocial.app.service.MyInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.thetasocial.app.service.MyService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

give me a clue to start from. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is local broadcast receiver.i.e., Anonymous class so you cannot find that receiver in the `manifest.xml`. This receiver has to be registered and unregistered which is mandatory and that too it has to be done in that particular activity (or) fragment, in that registering (or) unregister code we can find the broadcast intent filter name. In your case `BROADCAST_ACTION` is the name. Try to find the usage of the `BROADCAST_ACTION` in  the whole project. To find the usage in whole project, if you are using Android studio means shortcut is `ctrl`+`shift`+`F`. Your broadcast intent will be like below,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);

sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Note the intent filter name is just a string `BROADCAST_ACTION` should a constant value declared somewhere.

Hope this is helpful:)

Comment: Finally found it! you were right, it was a local intent. the problem was that I thought shortcut for Find usage in android studio is double `shift`. thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already upvoted the answer, but as I have less than 15 reputations, it doesn't show up :)

Answer (score 0):

find the sendBroadcast file or project...there you will see the intent and intent content that is broadcasted to be received by the BroadcastReciever...

Comment: in fact, i have not coded this file, I'm just modifying it to fulfill my needs.
when I make a new 'br', it comes up with an error as:
**Class 'Anonymous class derived from BroadcastReceiver' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onRecieve(Context, Intent)' in 'BroadcastReceiver'** . can this error help you?

Comment: now i get it, the intent is the intent containing message to be received by the broadcast...now to get more info you need to modify the target intent

Comment: exactly! now the question is where does this intent come from? how can I change it?